# Is it against rules to add 2 tags one of which is a subset of the other

Tags: discussion, tags

My question (link [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/49745/my-clock-has-disappeared)) originally had a [htc](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/htc) tag. Then another user edited it to remove [htc](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/htc) and added [htc-desire-x](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/htc-desire-x) instead. I felt both the tags are relevant and added [htc](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/htc) back. But the user again edited my post to remove [htc](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/htc). Before getting into a toggle edit fight, I was wondering if it's against rules to have both the tags in a question?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The manufacturer tags like [htc](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/htc) are more of a catch-all for when there isn't a more specific tag that applies (eg for obscure/unusual/new phone models), they're not needed if there's a more specific tag that applies, so aren't normally used, unless your problem is related to everything HTC related, which is rare.

Looking at the question, your problem could well be related to the HTC Sense custom interface, home screen and widgets that HTC add onto most of their phones now, so adding [htc-sense](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/htc-sense) tag in addition would make sense.

Answer (score 3):

It is not against the rule, though putting the two is useless (if you do a "htc" search, all `htc-` tags will show up). I just think that if your problem concern only one particular device, it should have `htc-device` as tag but not `htc`. `htc` tag should be used for problems related to all HTC in general.

Comment: How is the person who keeps editing my tag sure that this is a [tag:htc-desire-x] specific problem? I have no idea either way

Comment: @user93353: I don't, but that's the device you mentioned. I strongly prefer _not_ putting device-specific tags on questions unless it is _clear_ that the issue is specific to that type of device. In hindsight I probably should have left it off. The question is clearly not about HTC in general, which is why I removed that tag.

Comment: @AlEverett How do you know it's not specific to htc-desire-x or just all htcs. When I googled for this issue - I found 4-5 people reporting it in different forums - all htc owners.